# Django: Query Selected Info in Model Within Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I created some link with model-slug. But When I click my link, go to the page but return the empty value. I want to When I click any link, It will query value from the selected field like class_name or slug field.

this class list html page

```
{% extends "result/base.html" %} 
{% block title %}Class List Name{% endblock title %} {% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-offset-4">
        <h2>Class List</h2>
        {% for object in object_list  %}
        <a href="{% url 'result:class-detail' object.slug %}">{{object.class_name}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is models.py file

```
class ClassName(models.Model):
    class_name=models.CharField('Class Name', max_length=10)
    class_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class_updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.class_name
```

this is views.py file

```
class ClassListView(ListView):
    model=ClassName
    slug_field = 'slug'
    template_name='result/class_list.html'


class ClassDetailView(DetailView):
    model=ClassName
    slug_field = 'slug' 
    template_name='result/class_detail.html'



    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClassDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context['class_wise_std'] = StudentInfo.objects.filter(
            student_class_name__class_name__startswith=self.model.slug)

        return context
```

this is class details html page

```
{% extends "result/base.html" %} 
{% block title %}Class Detail's List{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
     {% for object in class_wise_std %}
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-offset-4" style="margin:20px 10px">


        <p>Name: {{object.student_name}}</p>
        <p>Class: {{object.student_class_name}}</p>
        <p>Father's Name: {{object.student_father_name}}</p>
        <p>Mother's Name: {{object.student_mother_name}}</p>
        <p>Roll: {{object.student_roll}}</p>

    </div>
     {% endfor %}

</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

this code

```
def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClassDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context['class_wise_std'] = StudentInfo.objects.filter(
            student_class_name__class_name__startswith=self.model.slug)

        return context
```

I found this problem happen with this code. I want to filter with **class_name** field in **ClassName** Model.

```
StudentInfo.objects.filter(student_class_name__class_name__startswith=self.model.slug)
```

But I can successfully query my targeted info this way.

```
StudentInfo.objects.filter(student_class_name__class_name__startswith='One')
```

But It is not an efficient way. Now, How can I implement dynamically this?

Comment: `slug` field is actually for an instance, not the whole model class. Also, i don't see you actually `slugify`-ing stuffs to save in the slug field. I presume you're getting the value `One` from the URL, why not deal with the URL instead of hardcoding?

Comment: How can I avoid hardcorded way?